# Rotating a sphere from point to point

Tags: opengl-es, geometry

I have a unit sphere that Is centered at the origin and my camera is also centered at the origin. The camera is facing z=-1. 
I change my view point by rotating the camera first about the x axis and then about the z axis. This is done in opengl es 1.1 using 
glrotate(phi,1,0,0);
glrotate(theta,0,0,1)

This esentially gives me a camera viewpoint where z=(0,0,1) is always the up vector. 
Using gluLookAt would give me the same result if I was specifying what point to look at.
I have also previously defined a projection matrix.

**Now for the real question:**

I click on the screen and the first point i click on is converted back through the projection matrix and modelview matrix and stored. i.e. 
pl=pixel location on screen, P=projection matrix, M=modelview matrix, ps=point on sphere in 3d

P*M*ps=pl
so ps=inv(M)*inv(P)*pl

Doing this step is trivial. The next part isnt.

Now I want to click anywhere else on the screen so therefore i get a plnew and I want to find out what matrix Mnew will cause a rotation such that the point ps will now appear at plnew on the screen i.e
P*Mnew*ps=plnew

This is obviously underconstrained and so I need to find the correct constraints. The constraints are based on the fact that I can only rotate using phi and theta as described in the intro to the question. So how do I solve for Mnew? or in other words phiNew and thetaNew.

By the way, the end "effect" im going for is that if a user clicks somewhere on the sphere and then drags the sphere then the point the user clicked on stays under the mouse during dragging AND the sphere stays upright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it quite easily after I posted the question despite having wasted an entire day banging my head yesterday.

let psnew=inv(M)*inv(P)*pl

I.e. psnew is just the location of the point plnew on the sphere.

v=psnew-ps

so (theta,phi)=convertToPolarCoordinates(v)

where the conversion is standard and can be found in wikipedia or anywhere else